# Activity gets finished when minimized

Tags: android, android-activity

I have this weird event that when I minimize an activity using home button, this activity gets finished. So when I try to relaunch the app, it gets back to the previous activity.

I don't put anything in the `onPause()` except some `boolean` value changes. And I also don't put any `finish()` on that activity.

Is there anything that could finish activity immediately when it gets minimized without calling finish()?

thank you.

Comment: Put your activity code here

Comment: check your onStop() code

Comment: check if your app crashes

Comment: I'm sorry, actually it's because of "noHistory" line at my manifest xml. I'm continuing old project and didn't look at the manifest yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In developer options, you might have enabled option named " don't keep activities " or noHistory attribute is true for activity manifest element

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "Don't keep activities" option is enabled on Developer options.